# How to remove badge notifications for whatsapp mac client

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, notifications

I have the whatsapp client installed in my mac. I want to remove the badges indicating of new messages, so the icon would always appear as no new messages -

[image]

Unfortunately, I could not find it in the notification center -

[image]  [image]

[image]  [image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

I do know it's possible as I did it before. Hopefully someone can help me with this one.

System: macbook pro late 2018, macos ventura 13.3.1

Comment: Is WhatsApp not just further down that list?

Comment: @Tetsujin nope, that's the issue

Comment: Hard to tell from your image, as it's scrolled right up to the A's not down to the W's.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have added the entire list of applications scrolled down

Comment: OK, thanks. I've shrunk the inlined version for data saving, click through for full size. BTW, *Pro tip:* To get several screenshots that will all line up neatly, use Cmd/Shift/5 which will let you draw a rectangle that's the same every time.

Comment: @Tetsujin Great, hopefully you can also help me with solving the issue 

Comment: Not something I can help with, sorry, never used whatsapp.

Comment: Pist : https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-remove-an-apps-red-notification-badge-app-not-appearing-in-notifications-panel.2376434/